# NextJs 13 - how to properly take advantage of SSR with folder structure

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, react-server-components

I have a question regarding the folder structure for NextJS 13 so to make use of server side rendering by default.

Currently my folder structure for my project is like this:

src/
app/
assets/
theme/
types/
utils/(contains all the api calls and helper functions)
algolia.ts
middleware.ts

My question would be, do I need to move all of those folders and files inside of the app directory to be able to take advantage of SSR and React server components?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not mindful of the particular changes or highlights it could present. Nonetheless, I can furnish you with some broad direction on the most proficient method to structure your Next.js project for server-side delivering (SSR) and Respond server parts in view of the current accepted procedures.

The envelope structure you've furnished appears to be sensible and lined up with normal examples in Next.js applications. In any case, to completely use server-side delivering and Respond server parts, you ought to guarantee that your parts and rationale are coordinated fittingly. How about we separate the organizers you have and examine their significance to SSR and Respond server parts:

```
src/ - This envelope is by all accounts your primary source registry, which is a decent practice. Keeping your source code separate from different documents is a spotless method for organizing your task.

application/ - Since Next.js utilizes a pages-based steering framework, your entrance point for pages ought to in a perfect world be inside this registry. Pages in the application/organizer will be consequently connected with courses. For instance, application/index.tsx would compare to the root course ("/"). This is where you ought to make your Next.js page parts that should be delivered on the server.

resources/ - This envelope could contain static resources like pictures, styles, and text styles. These resources can be utilized across your application, whether or not you're utilizing server-side delivering. The organizer structure for resources shouldn't affect SSR straightforwardly.

topic/ - This envelope could contain styles, subjects, or configuration related resources. Like the resources/organizer, the subject/envelope's items are commonly inconsequential to SSR.

types/ - This organizer could hold TypeScript type definitions. Types don't straightforwardly influence SSR all things considered.

utils/ - This envelope contains utility capabilities and Programming interface calls, which could be utilized in both server-side and client-side code. Coordinating your utility capabilities is a decent practice, yet its area doesn't straightforwardly influence SSR.

algolia.ts - Expecting this record contains Algolia-related code, its area is fine on the off chance that it's a utility or design document. What it's utilized inside your parts and whether it means for SSR rely upon the particulars of its execution.

middleware.ts - The motivation behind this record isn't obvious from the specific situation. Middleware could be utilized for taking care of solicitations, upgrading server-side delivering, or different purposes. In the event that it's connected with SSR, it might actually assume a part in your server-side delivering process.
```

To exploit SSR and Respond server parts in Next.js, you'll essentially have to zero in on making and coordinating your page parts (application/), guaranteeing that you're getting information and playing out any fundamental server-side rationale in these parts. The remainder of your venture structure is more about association, and you can orchestrate it such that seems OK for your application's necessities.

As a best practice, consistently allude to the authority Next.js documentation and any updates gave by the Next.js group to the most state-of-the-art data on project design and highlights, particularly in the event that there have been huge changes since my last information update.